# Convert varchar/timestamp col to Date field

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, substr

I have a varchar2 datatype field (`lmp_date`) that can return either `null` or what looks like a `timestamp` value.  Changing the database `data_type` to `DATE` isn't a possibility, so now I'm needing to convert this to a date, but with the values this column returns, I'm having some problems.

Returned values for `lmp_date` =
`null` or `2021-06-11-00.00.00`

Date format needed: `MM/DD/YYYY`

I've tried `cast`, `convert`, `substr+instr` to no avail

**ETA** - A couple example attempts (because there have been 10+:

`select  order_no, to_date(lmp_date) lmp_date from table_a` - with error message of 'ORA-01861: literal does not match format string'

`select order_no, to_date(substr(lmp_date, 1, instr(lmp_date, '00' -15))) lmp_date from table_a` - since `lmp_date` has `null` value possibilities, this doesn't work successfully

`select order_no, cast(lmp_date as date) lmp_date from table_a` - with same error message of 'ORA-01861: literal does not match format string'

`select order_no, to_date(lmp_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') lmp_date from table_a` - ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

There have been more attempts, this is all I can remember

Comment: I suggest what you *need* is a date datatype, which has no inherent format. Can you show how you tried the conversion?

Comment: Converting a string to a date is done with `to_date()`; but that has no human-readable format as already said, so do you need to keep it as a date or format it back to a string?

Comment: "Changing the database data_type to DATE isn't a possibility" - this would be **the only** proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a string to a date, use [the `to_date()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) with a suitable format mask:

```
to_date(lmp_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS')
```

The format model elements are [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A).

The result of that is a date data type, which is an internal 7-byte representation. Your client or application will format that for display, which may be based on your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, so you can modify that to change hot all dates are displayed; or use `to_char()` to convert the date back to a string, e.g.:

```
to_char(to_date(lmp_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

although if you want it as that string you can just use string manipulation with `substr()` and concatenation:

```
case when lmp_date is not null then
  substr(lmp_date, 6, 2) || '/' || substr(lmp_date, 9, 2) || '/' || substr(lmp_date, 1, 4)
end
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cb34931604a0075efb6c3305a2e0971)

---

When you do either of these:

```
to_date(lmp_date)
cast(lmp_date as date)
```

this also relies on your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT; and the "literal does not match format string" error indicates that it doesn't match the string, e.g. if you have the still-default 'DD-MON-RR' setting. It would actually work - for you in your current session - if you changed that setting. [I've shown that here just for info.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8764115058fa6cd075256c09e997446) But to work for anyone regardless of their session settings, you should use `to_date()` with an explicit format mask, and don't rely on or assume anything session-specific.

You were nearly there with:

```
to_date(lmp_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and again the "date format picture ends before converting entire input string" message tells you what is wrong - your string carries on past the YYYY-MM-DD elements. Expanding the format mask to match all of the string, as I did above, means it knows what each part means.

If you were really only interested in the date part then you could cut the end off the string:

```
to_date(substr(lmp_date, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

but that's only really useful if you have a mix of string values where some have times and some do not. (The resulting date will always have a time; it will just be midnight.) And if you have dates with different formats then it gets a bit complicated - partly why you shouldn't store dates as strings.

Comment: Your initial to_date(), to_char() and substr() functions worked to an extent, until I tried to pull them up and use them for calculations.  I am able to get data to return with the entire query, even with the date calculations, but if I attempt save it within our application, I receive a 'SQL expression is wrong' error.  If I attempt to export the data from the SQL window, when using the to_date() function I get a 'ORA-01843: not a valid month' error and if I use the substr() function, I get a 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' error

Comment: If you copy and paste from the result window you're back to a string value, formatted with NLS_DATE_FORMAT again. Depends what you mean by 'export' though, and which tool/IDE this is. 'SQL expression is wrong' isn't an Oracle error, so your application or some framework seems to be saying that, but I can't speculate as to why. You should probably ask a new question showing exactly what your application is doing and how it is trying to run the query, and the full error it gets.